# In Netbeans, is there a way to have a vertical line from the top to the bottom of the editor on the column where your cursor is?

Tags: netbeans, ide, coffeescript, editor, netbeans-7

Similar to the line that's normally at 80 characters, I would like to have a line follow my cursor and be displayed vertically on whichever column my cursor is on. It should extend to the top of the editor from the bottom; the same way the line is at column 80. This should be useful since I work in CoffeeScript a lot and need a quick way to match up indentations.

Answer (score 0):

My answer doesn't really answer you question (though I have to **answer** it in order to post a screenshot); are you aware of this feature:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I use that, but I think a line would be helpful still.